# What are the biological effects of assimilation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, borg

I am aware of some of the biological effects of assimilation by the Borg, such as the whitening of skin and the fact that hair stops growing (AFAIK), but what of other biological functions.  For example, what about cell replenishment, waste disposal (I know most of this comes from food and drink, but there are other wastes in the body) and the like?

Comment: Ah, _that's_ what happened to Picard's hair. I always wondered...

Comment: Getting divorced and ruining your husband's political career right when he looked like having a decent crack at becoming president?

Comment: This sounds like it's way too broad to answer in one go - there's a TON of stuff that happens and could be speculated to happen, to say nothing of whether or not any of it is ever reverseable (seven of nine would seem to suggest it's possible long after one might think it would be).

Comment: @Zibbobz - I've addressed the specific points raised in the question. An exhaustive list of biological processes affected by assimilation would take forever to compile and would be largely opinion-based; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_process

Comment: @Richard Nicely done. And, obviously, not all of that information is necessarily available - not every biological change that occurs during a Borg assimiliation is necessarily referenced in the series, or even fully understood in-canon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overall effects of assimilation on the physiology of humanoids is actually pretty well covered in the various Trek Series;

### Ingestion / Excretion

The Borg [don't eat](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/223.htm) and we can assume that they don't poop.

> **Crusher :** *The Borg don't ingest food. Their implants can synthesise any organic molecules the biological tissues require. What
>   they need is energy.*

It seems fairly likely that they excrete by simply reversing the process and converting the waste back into energy (in the same way that Jake Sisko [gets rid of the dining plates](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/507.htm) by putting them into the replicator)

### Tissue Repair

In the ENT: episode "[Regeneration](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/49.htm)", Starfleet scientists discover that Borg nanomachines are in charge of regulating the function of individual cells as well as repairing damage;

> **ROONEY:** (at microscope) *Take a look at this. Do you see those devices? They're repairing the cell membranes.*
>
> **DRAKE:** *What are they?*
>
> **MONINGER:** *I believe you're looking at a form of nanotechnology. I found thousands of these in both aliens. They're not just regenerating
>   the damaged tissue, they're repairing the mechanical components as
>   well.*

If you're after more information about the Borg, there is a very wide selection of information available [here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Assimilation).

Comment: Is there anything about there ability to survive hard vacuum?

Comment: @IG_42 - Their flesh is teeming with nano-bots. One assumes that they take care of all that